# Vuetify: Warning when changing theme of <v-overlay>

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, overlay, darkmode

I am pretty new to Vue.js and it's my first time with vuetify!

For the login component, I use a `<v-overlay>`, that works fine, but it is by default in dark theme. My form was white, it is now black.

I try to use dark and light like in this documentation: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-overlay/

when I do: `<v-overlay dark="false">`, it works great by I got a warning: `[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "dark". Expected Boolean, got String with value "false".`
Same thing when I try: `<v-overlay dark=false>` without quotes

Anyone know why?

thanks a lot, and have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `<v-overlay dark="false">`, the property `dark` is passed as a string.

You should use rather:

`<v-overlay :dark="false">`

Comment: Thanks man it works! will mark it as the solution

Comment: I don't know why but the overlay is also changing the width of my login form. Do you know why?